# What are these PCB coax holders called?

Tags: pcb, connector, surface-mount, coax

I have RG6 coax which I need to attach to a board and would like
to use a strain relief method as shown here:

[image]

What are these connector "claw grip" things called?
I believe this "claw grip" is soldered on but is not
used for electrical connection (the ground shield
is electrically connected by the lower most solder
blob in the picture, not through the metal claw
though the claw penetrates the outer insulation).
I can't find these for sale anywhere.

I am curious about alternatives to this also,
anything used to firmly connect a coax cable
to a PCB.

Comment: Cable tie and two holes in the PCB?  Cheap and easy, possibly problematic if you have mass production.

Comment: Be wicked careful soldering a coax shield like that.  The dielectric melts really easy, and with minimal effort, you'll get a short in that cable.  Especially true for RG-174, 188, and similar.  Alternatives: use a connector and mating PCB jack.  You'll be happier, users will be happier, repair techs will be happier.  Bean-counters: initially less happy, but then happier when repair/upgrade labor costs go down.

Comment: Just be aware the the shielding effectiveness of the coax shield is greatly reduced with the approach you've shown.  This is because the shield does not enclose the center conductor at the PCB end.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a clamp, consider the board-in connectors for coax cable from TE:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- [TE Connectivity](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-226177-2.html) - 226177-2 - [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/226177-2/292522)
- [TE Connectivity](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-226286-2.html) - 226286-2
- [TE Connectivity](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-9-226176-0.html) - 9-226176

https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-9-226176-0.html

[image: TE 9-226176-0]

{TE connectivity}

Comment: What is the advantage of these over the one in my photo?  The one in my photo seems to use less PCB area and be better for RF (because the termination is more abrupt), so I don't see why these would be better.  Anyway, I'm still hoping someone can find something closer to the one in my photo, so I know what to call it and can test it out.

Comment: A reliable and repeatable  connection to the PCB. A clean electrical connection to the shield (as opposed to loose strands from twisting the braid into a bundle. A professional look (if that matters to you). Constant impedance (if used for RF). Faster installation (if this is for manufacturing).